# match two string and replace non-match char to + in java

Tags: java

Modify first string such that all characters are replaced by plus sign(+) except the char that are available in second string if one or more char of first string appear in second string, they will not be replaced by +  (ignore case)

String input1 ="New York";
String input2 ="New Jersy";

String out="New Y+r+";

I have tried this:

```
String input1 ="New York";
String input2 ="New Jersy";
String str[] = input1.split([New Jersy]);

for(String s:str) {
    if(s.equals("")) // same pattern else // + should be printed }
```

Comment: Okay, so we know what you want to do... what's the question? How far have you got? What does your code look like, and what's the problem with it?

Comment: i hv tried thisString input1 ="New York"; 
String input2 ="New Jersy";

String str[] = input1.split([New Jersy]);

for(String s:str)
{
 if(s.equals(""))
 // same pattern
 else
 // + should be printed
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution works but with a slight modification like below. Remove the `(?i)` part if you dont want to take case sensitivity into account.

```
public class StringReplacer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "New York";
        String str2 = "New Jersy";

        for(String s : str1.split("(?i)[" + str2 +"]")){
            if(s.trim().length() > 0){
                str1 = str1.replace(s, "+");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(str1); // Prints New Y+r+
    }

}
```